# Update Internet Explorer to newer version

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

Is it recommended to replace (install through windows update) IE8 to IE9 in Windows7? Does it really *entirely* replace IE to newer version a on given system? (also Windows Explorer?)
It seems that IE is tightly integrated with the system. I don't know that I should install IE9 or cumulative updates for IE8 - which method do you use and which brings less trouble?

Comment: The simplest answer could be: No, it's not recommended. Stay with Firefox and Safari :)

Comment: I use SRWare Iron by default. I'm just curious about how this update affects the system. And still - I'd like to hear an answer from someone that knows that update IE8 to IE9 really replaces IE in my system, or only installs IE9 browser but core IE8 of the system is still the same?

Comment: I always install the latest avaliable IE. Just because it should/might get security updates faster. And since it's a key component (tightly integrated), security is important. But I've got no back info on this. :/

Answer (score 1):

*Recommended by who?*

---

From a security standpoint, being up-to-date to the latest stable version is a must. And for that reason, you should update to Internet Explorer 9, which has become stable 2 months ago.

As for core stuff, either Internet Explorer or your Operating System will update them; that's why it is important to not just update one thing, but everything you can.